# Meaning of being isomorphic over/under $c$ in category theory

Tags: category-theory, definition, slice-category

To the point:

> What does being isomorphic over/under an object $c$ mean?

Let $x,y,c$ be objects in a category $\mathsf C$, and let's concentrate on "over". I think "$x\cong y$ over $c$" should mean that there is an isomophism $h:f\to g$ in the slice category $\mathsf C/c$ between some morphisms $f:x\to c$ and $g:y\to c$. This of course implies that $x\cong y$ in $C$. but is stronger. Graphically, there should exist $f,g$ and $h$ ($h$ an iso in $\mathsf C$) such that this diagram commutes:

$\hspace{4.25cm}$[image]

But could it somehow mean that for **all** $f:x\to c$ and **all** $g:y\to c$, we have $f=gh$? This sounds too strong to me, but it would remedy the fact that $f$ and $g$ should be considered part of the data in my first interpretation.

---

For context, I read the claim in a exercise by Riehl that if $F$ and $G$ are naturally isomorphic functors $\mathsf C\to \mathsf{Set}$, then "$\int\! F \cong \int\! G$ over $\mathsf C$", where $\int\!F$ is the category of elements. Here, the relevant slice category is $\mathsf{CAT}/\mathsf C$, where $\mathsf{CAT}$ is the category of locally small categories. I've found a couple of other uses of the same phrasing through google, some by Riehl as well.

I interpret the claim as pertaining specifically to the canonical projections to $\mathsf C$. I.e. for a natural isomorphism $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$, we have an isomorphism of categories $\int\!\alpha:\int\!F\to\int\!G$ (my notation), such that this diagram of functors commutes:

$\hspace{4.25cm}$[image]

Here, $\int\!\alpha: (c,x) \mapsto (c,\alpha_cx), f \mapsto f$.

This should all be true, but is it the right interpretation of the claim?

Comment: No:  the fixed objects are the maps $f$ and $g$:  $x$ and $y$ are not objects in the over category.

Comment: In other words, in the over category you have $f \cong g$ not $x \cong y$.

Comment: @Randall Yes, I know! So what I'm asking is how to interpret such (a priori senseless) statements as those in my question. The example with categories of elements is taken verbatim from Category Theory in Context (Riehl), with no special definition given for such phrasing. Another example is in Prop. 3.1 of [this nLab page](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/cograph+of+a+functor). Perhaps this is not exactly standard language?

Comment: To be clear, I understand that my $\int\!\alpha$ for example can be seen as an isomorphism $\int \!F\to\int\! G$ in $CAT$ or an isomorphism $\Pi_F\to\Pi_G$ in $CAT/C$.

Comment: Oh, I see your confusion now.

Comment: Yes, I think your hunch is right:  "over" in the sense where the "down" arrows are the canoncial ones given as part of the structure.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you agree then. That makes sense to me.

Comment: Yea, “$x$ and $y$ are isomorphic over $z$” means there’s an isomorphism in the slice over $z$ between the two specific, hopefully obvious, objects with domains $x$ and $y$ that the author has in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes, your interpretation at the bottom of the post is correct.

When category theorists (and most other mathematicians, for that matter) write that two objects $x$ and $y$ are isomorphic over $c$ in some category $\mathcal{C}$, what they really mean is that $x$ and $y$ are objects $x \rightarrow c$ and $y \rightarrow c$ in the overcategory $\mathcal{C}_{/c}$, and that there exists a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
x @>{h}>> y\\
@V{f}VV @V{g}VV \\
c @>{id}>> c,
\end{CD}$$
with $h$ an isomorphism.
I draw it as a square to emphasize that $\mathcal{C}_{/c}$ is a category whose objects are (vertical) arrows and whose morphisms are commutative squares where the bottom arrow is the identity.
Essentially, saying that $x$ is isomorphic to $y$ over $c$ is a slight but common abuse of notation, which might be confusing for newcomers.

It might be an informative and fun exercise to show that commutative squares/triangles as above with $h$ an isomorphism are precisely the isomorphisms in the overcategory $\mathcal{C}_{/c}$.

It is also amusing to deduce what your stronger notion (for some isomorphism $h$, $f = gh$ for all $f,g$) implies about $c$; try letting $h$ be the identity.